# How can I add text to the top of QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTextEdit` and I am trying to insert text to top of that using following code

```
void HuggleLog::InsertText(QString text)
{
    ui->textEdit->cursorForPosition(QPoint(0,0));
    ui->textEdit->insertPlainText(text);
}
```

I am trying to move the cursor to beginning of text area so that text get inserted infront of current text, but it doesn't work. What is a correct way? There is append() method but no prepend.

Comment: Just a trick: `QString newtext = textEdit->toPlainText(); newtext.prepend(text); textEdit->setPlainText(newText);`

Comment: @vahancho Sounds cool and in fact I tried that before, but I am afraid this would require far more CPU as it would need to render whole text everytime from scratch. Also it was crashing my app randomly when I needed to insert lot of text (called that function like thousand times within few seconds)

Comment: @ Peter, yeah. I didn't pretend to say that this solution is the best one. That's why I called it "a trick":) BTW, if you prepend text with other methods, won't it provoke a redraw too - your text will shift right/down anyways?

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```
QString oldText = ui->textEdit->toPlainText(); // or toHtml()
ui->textEdit->setPlainText(text + oldText);    // or setText() or setHtml()
```

Comment: This was crashing my app for unknown reasons (when I was doing that many times within short time), but I will try to play with that a bit

Comment: 'class QTextEdit' has no member named 'text'

Comment: I figured it is crashing because I insert it using different thread :), so yes, this kind of works, when I replace text() with toPlainText() and setText to setPlainText()

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot there's no text() method. Either you have html or plain text. Using plain text could be faster if you don't need formatting.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you're looking for is http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qtextedit.html#moveCursor with http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtgui/qtextcursor.html#MoveOperation-enum. Should look like:

```
ui->textEdit->moveCursor(QTextCursor::start, 0);
```

Comment: 'start' is not a member of 'QTextCursor'

Comment: @Petr, `QTextCursor::Start` (with capital 'S').