# How to prepend text to QPlainTextEdit in Qt and keep scrollbar steady?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QPlainTextEdit`,which I have to populate in two ways.

When I want to add text at the end , I can do that very simply by using `appendPlainText()` function provided. I do this when Vertical scrollbar hits lower boundary and if user scrolls after that , then I append new text. This performs very smoothly.

But What I want to do is when user scrolls up and scroll bar hits the upper boundary, and if user scrolls after that(in upward direction), I want to prepend text to it. But the problem is **there is no such function prependPlainText()** and therefore, I first get plaintext from my `QPlainTextEdit`, which is a `QString`, use `prepend` of `QString`, and then append new text to the `QPlainTextEdit`. But problem is scroll bar goes down right after I append text to my `QPlainTextEdit`, **What I want is keep the scroll bar at upper boundary**.
 Just like scroll bar remains at lower boundary in previous scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Combining [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30409034/875020) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18851571/875020) id go with

```
ui->qpte->document()->setPlainText(text + "\n" + ui->qpte->toPlainText());
```

with `qpte` being the name of the `QPlainTextEdit` and `text` a `QString` with the new text. `ui` is a pointer to your `UI::MainWindow` or `QWidget` or so.

Not sure if this is performance wise (and certainly doesnt scale well)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use [x29a's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49197613/20658771) you might consider using it like this:

```
ui->qpte->document()->setPlainText(text + "\n" + ui->qpte->toHtml());
```

so that your previous formatting does get discarded.

Or maybe it's better to use what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52702009/20658771) like this:

```
QTextCursor cursor = QTextCursor(ui->qpte->document());
cursor.setPosition(0);
ui->qpte->setTextCursor(cursor);
ui->qpte->insertHtml(text);
```