# How to insert text at the top of a QTextEdit widget?

Tags: python, insert, pyqt, append, qtextedit

I have a simple `QTextEdit` form which I am using as a sort of log. Events are written down into the form, so the user can review history events.
I am using `textEdit.append()` to add new lines to the form.
However, `textEdit.append()`, appends the text to the end of the buffer, so the newest events are shown on the bottom. Is there a reasonable way to append to the beginning, so that the newest events are shown on the top?

Comment: Have you tried something like textEdit.text = str_to_append + textEdit.text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `insertPlainText` method to insert text anywhere in the current text. Place a cursor to specify where the text is to be inserted. In your case you'd place it at the start:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextCursor

# set the cursor position to 0
cursor = QTextCursor(textEdit.document())
# set the cursor position (defaults to 0 so this is redundant)
cursor.setPosition(0)
textEdit.setTextCursor(cursor)

# insert text at the cursor
textEdit.insertPlainText('your text here')
```